# can i find text in the computer's RAM (windows 7)

Tags: python, memory, windows-7, vb6, ram

I'd like to scan the whole RAM on a local machine for a string / hex code.

- Only read access is needed, not write.
- Windows 7, 64bit & 32bit computers.
- The machine has no access restrictions.
- my toolbox: python, vb, and command line uitlities

("HeapMemView" is working only for a given process, and so - irrelevant to my task)

**How can it be done?** which libraries or functions give read access to the RAM? I couldn't find answers via google about it - only methods for testing RAM chips.

**EDIT**

i don't understand why the down votes.  What is wrong with the **question** ? where's the website police?

Comment: What is the objective here?

Comment: automating a program written in non-accessibility way (i think borland)

Comment: You send a program Windows' Messages to control it. See all messages (most start wm_) and SendMessage API call.

Comment: @Noodles : i'm not looking to control it, just to get its data

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The CPU will stop you. Look up virtual machines and virtual memory.

Comment: No. Each process thinks it's the only one on the computer. The only way programs share memory is via memory mapped files (incl the page file).

Comment: The point is the CPU and Windows is designed as a core principal to prevent this. Initially it was mainly to stop programs crashing other programs. Now security is a big reason. You can load a DLL into user mode programs and use that to write to a file. But see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197571 but it won't work on all OSs in all configurations.

Comment: Its trivial to read the memory of another process, use `ReadProcessMemory()`

Comment: He already can read the memory from one process. NTSD will read memory of one process.

Comment: why would READING memory from other processes will crash a program? (yes, security is still issue. not in my case, but sure.)